# R charToRaw and enc2utf8 problems in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am reading a cvs file with three columns into a dataframe using

```
proj_epsg <- data.frame(read.csv('file.csv', encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

and get two of the three columns named as input for a a Select Box

```
epsg_choices <- setNames(as.numeric(proj_epsg$EPSG), as.character(proj_epsg$Name))
```

When I run the app the console will be filled with warnings of type:

```
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

Hence, I tried to read the data already with UTF-8 encoding in. I also saved the cvs file in UTF-8, changing the encoding from ASCII to UTF-8.

How do I get a correct `charToRaw` result, without warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution, but I am not happy with it...

In the ui.R file I defined an `htmlOutput`

```
htmlOutput(selectInProj')
```

and in the server.R file I wrote the following function

```
function(input, output) {
  proj_epsg <- data.frame(read.csv('file.csv', encoding = 'UTF-8'))
  eps_choices <- setNames(as.numeric(proj_epsg$EPSG), as.character(proj_epsg$Name)
  output$selectInProj <- renderUI({
    selectInput('in_start', label = h4('Projection start points'), epsg_choices)
  })
}
```

It works, there are no warnings about the encoding, and the Selectboxes are getting the correct input. However, renderUI now takes a while, since the cvs fiel contains a bit more than 5000 lines.

The content of the SelectBoxes could be created before, so the user does not have to wait that long.

Any suggestions on it?